# Grouping a list of string in java

Tags: java

I am new to java and i am trying to group a list of numeric string base on their first 5 characters and last 5 characters.

E.g

User input:
12345678901
12345678902
12345678903
12345678904
12345578901

The system should output
12345678901
12345578901

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey, could you please elaborate how exactly the program should calculate the output/which of the Strings should be output?

Comment: Hi, my apologies. The program should compare the first 5 characters and the last five characters with another strings. If all are equals, then the program should output.